# Is it possible to update a pair of values in TSQL from a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

Can I update a pair of columns using the same subquery instead of calling it twice?

```sql
-- Table D contains a Date and a ProcessId

UPDATE T1
SET (Val1, Val2) = (
    SELECT SUM(Val1A), SUM(Val2A) 
    --Val1A and Val2A are equations and are not taken from just one table but multiple
    FROM D
      INNER JOIN T8 ON T8.ProcessId = D.ProcessId
      INNER JOIN T4 ON T4.Id = T8.T4Id
      INNER JOIN T6 ON T4.Id = T6.T4Id
    WHERE D.Date <= @ProcessDate AND T6.T4Id = T1.T4Id)
FROM T1
  INNER JOIN T4 ON T4.Id = T1.T4Id
  INNER JOIN T5 ON T5.Id = T1.T5Id
  INNER JOIN T6 ON T4.Id = T6.T4Id
  INNER JOIN T7 ON T7.Id = T4.T7Id
```

Instead of doing

```sql
UPDATE T1
SET Val1 = (SELECT Val1A
     FROM T2 
       INNER JOIN T8 ON T8.T2Id = T2.Id
       INNER JOIN T4 ON T4.Id = T8.T4Id
       INNER JOIN T6 ON T4.Id = T6.T4Id
     WHERE T4.T1Id = T1.Id)
    Val2 = (SELECT Val2A
     FROM T2 
       INNER JOIN T8 ON T8.T2Id = T2.Id
       INNER JOIN T4 ON T4.Id = T8.T4Id
       INNER JOIN T6 ON T4.Id = T6.T4Id
     WHERE T4.T1Id = T1.Id)
FROM T1
  INNER JOIN T4 ON T4.Id = T1.T4Id
  INNER JOIN T5 ON T5.Id = T1.T5Id
  INNER JOIN T6 ON T4.Id = T6.T4Id
  INNER JOIN T7 ON T7.Id = T4.T7Id
```

Note: The FROM and WHERE clauses are obviously more complex than this

Comment: Why not just `JOIN` in the `FROM`?

Comment: The inner query is used to calculate the new values based on a date and Id passed from the outer query so a simple join won't work

Comment: What date? All the joins are on `ID`s.

Comment: I feel like your attempt to "simplify" the problem is muddying it. If you post a more representative example, that would help us help you. talking about dates, for example, doesn't make sense when there are no date columns in your SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `outer apply` instead:

```
UPDATE T1
    SET Val1 = X.Val1,
        Val2 = X.Val2    
FROM T1 JOIN
     T4
     ON T4.Id = T1.T4Id JOIN
     T5
     ON T5.Id = T1.T5Id JOIN
     T6
     ON T4.Id = T6.T4Id
     T7
     ON T7.Id = T4.T7Id OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(Val1A), SUM(Val2A) 
    --Val1A and Val2A are equations and are not taken from just one table but multiple
      FROM D JOIN
           T8
           ON T8.ProcessId = D.ProcessId JOIN
           T4
           ON T4.Id = T8.T4Id JOIN
           T6
           ON T4.Id = T6.T4Id
      WHERE D.Date <= @ProcessDate AND 
            T6.T4Id = T1.T4Id
     ) x;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `CROSS JOIN` and subquery. Though the logic in the above is *really* odd; you're updating every row in `T1` even though it has no relationship to `T2` and `T3`. Also, based you the above, the subquery can only return 1 row, so your tables `T2` and `T3` must only have one row too.

```sql
UPDATE T1
SET Val1 = sq.Val1A,
    Val2 = sq.Val2A
FROM dbo.T1
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT T2.Val1A,
                        T2.Val2A
                 FROM dbo.T2
                      JOIN dbo.T3 ON T2.Id = T3.Id) sq;
```

---

For your latest edit, you would write your upper query as the following:

```sql
UPDATE T1
SET Val1 = Val1A,
    Val2 = Val2A
FROM T1
  INNER JOIN T4 ON T4.Id = T1.T4Id
  INNER JOIN T5 ON T5.Id = T1.T5Id
  INNER JOIN T6 ON T4.Id = T6.T4Id
  INNER JOIN T7 ON T7.Id = T4.T7Id
  INNER JOIN T4 ON T4.T1Id = T1.Id
  INNER JOIN T6 ON T4.Id = T6.T4Id
  INNER JOIN T8 ON T4.Id = T8.T4Id
  INNER JOIN T2 ON T8.T2Id = T2.Id
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake on my part, I've updated the code to reflect my problem a bit more closely.